# Perl: Getting element in array or matrix

Tags: arrays, perl, matrix

I have a variable which can either be an array or a matrix (because a matrix with only one row gets transformed into an array). What can I use to access the elements whether the variable is an array or a matrix?

Example:

```
v = [[1,2,3]];
v[0][0] gives an error;
v = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
v[0][0] gives 1;
```

Comment: could you show *actual code*? That isn't Perl, as the variables would have sigils etc. It's impossible to tell why one line gives an error and the other one doesn't if we can't see the actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, here's one way that will give access to both:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $v = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ] ];
print $v->[0][0], "\n";    # prints 1

$v = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ];
print $v->[1][0], "\n";    # prints 4
```

`[ ... ]` creates an anonymous array, and a reference to that array is returned when it's evaluated--like in the assignment `$v =` or within another `[ ... ]`.  Both print statements show the results of dereferencing twice, and could have been written as:

```
print $v->[0]->[0], "\n";    # prints 1
```

There is no difference between the two data *structures*; the second, however, has more data.

Hope this helps!